# C++ loop each non-prime

Tags: c++, primes, do-loops

I'm trying to do this :

1. The User chooses one number
2. The program calls the `isaPrime()` function so we see if number is prime or not.

I wanted to do a loop so every time the number is not a prime, the user has to choose a new value.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime (int num)
{
    if (num <=1)
        return false;
    else if (num == 2)
        return true;
    else if (num % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        bool prime = true;
        int divisor = 3;
        double num_d = static_cast<double>(num);
        int upperLimit = static_cast<int>(sqrt(num_d) +1);

        while (divisor <= upperLimit)
        {
            if (num % divisor == 0)
                prime = false;
            divisor +=2;
        }
        return prime;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int p;
    do {
      cout << "p : ";
      cin >> p;
      isPrime(p);
    } while (isPrime(p));

}
```

Comment: This is not really funny...
If I came here it means I couldn't do it by myself.
If you are just here for useless post like that just get out of there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Question is off-topic period! What do you go to do now?

Comment: I did all these things...

Comment: So, what's stopping you from editing your post and pasting the code, not a picture of the code?

Comment: _"I did it all these things..."_ You like to share with us not using off site links also??

Comment: Oh I understand now, okay sorry for this... I'll post the code the next time.

Comment: Why do you call `isPrime` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should handle your user I/O loop. You just need to replace the `isPrime` function with your own implementation.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define isPrime(x) (1)

int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;

    const int maxchar = 5;
    string nationname;
    int input;
    int running = 1;

    while ( running )
    {
        cout << "Enter a number:";
        cin >> input;
        if ( isPrime(input ) )
        {
            // Do something
            running = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not a prime number. Please try again!" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the do loop your code will work.  This is because your loop will run as long as the isprime returns true, and will stop running when isprime returns false.

Also if you want to display whether or not the number is prime you should use `cout << isPrime(p);`

thus your main funcion should look like

```
int main()
{
  int p;
  cout << "p : ";
  cin >> p;
  cout << isPrime(p);
}
```

Comment: That's not what I wanted, Dogbert answered.
But thanks for the contribution !

Answer (score 0):

According to your question: When user chooses a non prime number the loop iterates. What you are doing is reverse so just replace

```
else{
bool prime =false   //replaced to true
//your code
while (divisor <= upperLimit)
    {
        if (num % divisor == 0)
            {
                prime = true;   //replaced to true 
                break;
            }
        divisor +=2;
    }
    return prime;
```